# Returning value from Scala future completion

Tags: scala, functional-programming, slick, future

Coming from a Java background, I have been trying to teach myself Scala for some time now. As part of that, I am doing a small pet project that exposes a HTTP endpoint that saves the `registration number`of a vehicle against the `owner` and returns the status.

To give more context, I am using [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/) as FRM which performs DB operations asynchronously and returns a `Future`.
Based on the output of this Future, I want to set the `status` variable to return back to the client.

Here, is the code

```
def addVehicleOwner(vehicle: Vehicle): String = {
    var status = ""
    val addFuture = db.run((vehicles returning vehicles.map(_.id)) += vehicle)
    addFuture onComplete {
      case Success(id) => {
        BotLogger.info(LOGTAG, s"Vehicle registered at $id ")
        status = String.format("Registration number - '%s' mapped to owner '%s' successfully", vehicle.registration,
          vehicle.owner)
        println(s"status inside success $status") //--------- (1)
      }
      case Failure(e: SQLException) if e.getMessage.contains("SQLITE_CONSTRAINT") => {
        status = updateVehicleOwner(vehicle)
        BotLogger.info(LOGTAG, s"Updated owner='${vehicle.owner}' for '${vehicle.registration}'")
      }
      case Failure(e) => {
        BotLogger.error(LOGTAG, e)
        status = "Sorry, unable to add now!"
      }
    }
    exec(addFuture)
    println(s"Status=$status") //--------- (2)
    status
  }

  // Helper method for running a query in this example file:
  def exec[T](sqlFuture: Future[T]):T = Await.result(sqlFuture, 1 seconds)
```

This was fairly simple in Java. With Scala, I am facing the following problems:

- The expected value gets printed at (1), but (2) always prints empty string and same is what method returns. Can someone explain why?
- I even tried marking the `var status` as `@volatile var status`, it still evaluates to empty string.
- I know, that the above is not the functional way of doing things as I am muting state. What is the clean way of writing code for such cases.
- Almost all the examples I could find described how to map the result of `Success` or handle `Failure` by doing a `println`. I want to do more than that.
- What are some good references of small projects that I can refer to? Specially, that follow TDD.

Comment: The first thing to notice is that you are waiting on addFuture, but it's the future created via `onComplete` that actually mutates `status`. That may be the reason your println isn't giving what you expect. However, for all the reasons mentioned in the various docs, if you find yourself using Await.result in anything other than tests you are probably missing the essential nature of futures. Perhaps you just return the status value itself in the future (rather than mutating an external var) and just pass that future around until someone actually needs the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on `status` to complete inside the closure, you can `recover` over the `Future[T]` which handle the exception if they occur, and always returns the result you want. This is taking advantage of the nature of expressions in Scala:

```
val addFuture = 
  db.run((vehicles returning vehicles.map(_.id)) += vehicle)
    .recover {
      case e: SQLException if e.getMessage.contains("SQLITE_CONSTRAINT") => {
        val status = updateVehicleOwner(vehicle)
        BotLogger.info(
          LOGTAG, 
          s"Updated owner='${vehicle.owner}' for '${vehicle.registration}'"
        )
        status
      }
      case e => {
        BotLogger.error(LOGTAG, e)
        val status = "Sorry, unable to add now!"
        status
      }
    }

val result: String = exec(addFuture)
println(s"Status = $result")
result
```

Note that `Await.result` should not be used in any production environment as it synchronously blocks on the `Future`, which is exactly the opposite of what you actually want. If you're already using a `Future` to delegate work, you want it to complete *asynchronously*. I'm assuming your `exec` method was simply for testing purposes.